# User's Job Title in Liferay Theme

Tags: liferay, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

I'm trying to include the value of the user field "Job Title" in a Liferay-Theme (6.1.20), but I can't find the proper VM-variable.

If there isn't one, how would I go about displaying that information or (alternatively) a custom field for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. There's no special VM-variable, but you can use the $user variable like so:

`$user.getJobTitle()`